# Grafana email alerts links showing defaulthost e.g. 127.0.0.1

Tags: grafana

Grafana email alerts links showing default host e.g. 127.0.0.1. How do I change them to the correct host e.g. Grafana_server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure [root_url](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/#root-url) in Grafana configuration and restart your Grafana instance. For example:

```
root_url = https://example.com/
```

Comment: I've already got that as the correct address (Grafana_server) but emails are still coming through as the 127 address.  I've restarted the service too.  Do i need the semi colon ( ; ) before Grafana_server?

Comment: Semi colon ( ; ) is a comment; see example and doc link, pls.

Comment: The `root_url` should be in `[server]` section.